# Do I actually only have 3 days to save Miller?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So, I got to Chapter One, and Ocelot kept talking about he thinks Miller "probably has about 3 days left". This seems like an arbitrary number he chose.

When I finally got control of my character, I listened to all the audio tapes I'd unlocked and noticed that about 6 hours of game time had passed in the 20 or so minutes I'd been listening to them.

This made me wonder... am I actually under a time constraint to save Miller, or can I run around and explore as much as I want before proceeding with my main objective?

Answer (score 9):

If you wait long enough, the mission will fail when you rescue Miller, ending in a Time Paradox.

Comment: I'd recommend a video that shows more of what happens, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfHeqccEfZU). The one you used skips the cutscene.

Comment: Actually, I recorded this quite by accident. I left for work in the middle of trying to get some mist parasites.

Comment: Edited in the better video.